# Setting parameter dependencies in ArcGIS python toolboxes?

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox, parameters

I'm trying to build a Python Toolbox where the user selects a layer and then specifies a column in that layer. According to the [Parameter](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/parameter.htm) documentation, that is done via the `parameterDependencies` attribute of an `arcpy.Parameter` instance. That same documentation says that you need a list of integers specifying the indexes of the downstream parameters. Presumably they reference the list of parameters you're supposed to return in the `getParameterInfo` method of your tool's class.

However, even the most basic of examples fails:

```
import arcpy

class Flooder(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = "1 - Create Flood Scenarios"
        self.description = ""
        self.canRunInBackground = True

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        polygons = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Zones", 
            name="polygons",
            datatype="DEFeatureClass", 
            parameterType="Required",  
            direction="Input"
        )

        tidegate_column = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="ID column", 
            name="tidegate_column",
            datatype="Field",
            parameterType="Required", 
            direction="Input"
        )

        return [polygons, tidegate_column]

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):      
        polygons = parameters[0]
        tgcol = parameters[1]
        polygons.parameterDependencies = [1]

f = Flooder()
p = f.getParameterInfo()
f.updateParameters(p)
```

Which raises:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-504b0ce950cb> in <module>()
      1 f = Flooder()
      2 params = f.getParameterInfo()
----> 3 f.updateParameters(params)

<ipython-input-22-c19883891bbb> in updateParameters(self, parameters)
     11         polygons = parameters[0]
     12         tgcol = parameters[1]
---> 13         polygons.parameterDependencies = [1]
     14 
     15 

C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\_base.pyc in _set(self, val)
     87                     return val
     88         try:
---> 89             return setattr(self._arc_object, attr_name, cval(val))
     90         except AttributeError:
     91             raise NameError(

ValueError: ParameterObject: Dependency list value out of range
```

Any idea what's going wrong?

I have triple checked my code and the documentation, and I'm passing the specified list of integers that the property needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation appears to be wrong. It doesn't want a list of integers. It seems to want a list of integers as *strings*.

Hopefully, Esri updates the documentation, or even better, allows you to pass actual parameters (or their names) in the future. Change the example above to the following and it will work:

```
import arcpy

class Flooder(object):
    # [snip]

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):      
        polygons = parameters[0]
        tgcol = parameters[1]
        polygons.parameterDependencies = ["1"]  # <-- ints as strings 0_o

f = Flooder()
p = f.getParameterInfo()
f.updateParameters(p)
```

Per the comments below, you can also pass the parameter's name. But that still seems messy and a bit too [hard-coded/magic-number-y](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) for my taste.

So instead, if you create your parameters as class properties, you can operate in a much more literate fashion:

```
class Flooder(BaseTool_Mixin):
    def __init__(self):
        self._polygons = None
        self._tidegate_column = None

    @staticmethod
    def _set_parameter_dependency(downstream, *upstream):
        """ Set the dependecy of a downstream arcpy.Parameter
        to the (potentially many) upstream arcpy.Parameters
        """
        downstream.parameterDependencies = [u.name for u in upstream]


    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        """ Automatically called when any parameter is updated in the
        GUI.
        """
        # tidegate_columns looks into the polygons layer to get a list of fields
        self._set_parameter_dependency(self.tidegate_column, self.polygons)

    @property
    def polygons(self):
        if self._polygons is None:
            self._polygons = arcpy.Parameter(
                displayName="Tidegate Zones of Influence", name="polygons",
                datatype="DEFeatureClass", parameterType="Required", direction="Input"
            )
        return self._polygons

    @property
    def tidegate_column(self):
        if self._tidegate_column is None:
            tidegate_column = arcpy.Parameter(
                displayName="Column with Tidegate IDs", name="tidegate_column",
                datatype="Field", parameterType="Required", direction="Input"
            )
        return self._tidegate_column

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """ Returns all parameter definitions"""
        return [self.polygons, self.tidegate_column]
```

Comment: Parameter names will work for Python toolboxes. (might also want to include `parameterDependencies` in `getParameterInfo`)

Comment: @DWynne good to know. I'll update the answer with a more complete solution that uses python properties and a static method that makes the whole process much more readable.

Comment: I believe there is a syntax error in ```downstream.parameterDependencies = [u.name for u in *upstream]```. It should read ```downstream.parameterDependencies = [u.name for u in upstream]```.  Notice the parameter ```upstream``` has no '*' when referenced in the function.

Comment: you're right @dhollema. I'll fix it

Comment: If you are right about the documentation being wrong, then I recommend not just hoping that someone else will notice and fix it.  Use your local support team to submit a documentation error report. If you want any software behaviour to change then submit an ArcGIS Idea.

Comment: The parent class BaseTool_Mixin, where can I find it, or did you create it your self?

Comment: @PaalPedersen https://github.com/Geosyntec/python-propagator/blob/master/propagator/base_tbx.py#L10